# It's possible make jquery.live() work with load?

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I can't make $.live() work with "load" event, like:

```
$(".animate").live("load", function(){
   $(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
})
```

Details:

I have a page with ajax results. In these ajax I can have many error messages with class "animate". So, I want every time the browser loads a element with "animate" class, browser animates it, usind fadeIn.

It's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do it with the **[.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)**

```
 $('.animate').ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);
 });
```

*Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the **ajaxComplete** event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxComplete()` method are executed at this time.*

**just-a-tip:** perhaps combine it with **[.ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)**

```
$('.animate').ajaxSend(function() {
  $(this).show().fadeOut(1000);
});
```

*Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery triggers the **ajaxSend** event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxSend()` method are executed at this time.*

Comment: Needs adjusting a little depending on _which_ AJAX request completed, but otherwise a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure the element is hidden (via css) before it is sent to the browser.  Then, a setTimeout(...) loop could be used to find those which are hidden and begin the animation.